# data.table - delete columns programmatically

Tags: r, data.table

What is the best practice to delete columns programmatically in `data.table`?

The following works:

```
DT[, c("a", "b") := NULL]
```

But when trying to do this using a variable that stores column names

```
cols.to.del <- c("a", "b")
DT[, cols.to.del := NULL]
```

it fails badly as `cols.to.del` is not evaluated in the correct environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can wrap it inside the brackets, and then assign (`:=`) to 'NULL' (preferred way)

```
DT[, (cols.to.del) := NULL]
```

Or another option (in case we don't want to wrap it with brackets) would be to loop over the 'cols.to.del' in a `for` loop and assign to NULL

```
for(j in seq_along(cols.to.del)){
    DT[, cols.to.del[j] := NULL]
}
```

---

Or for subsetting the columns, we can use `setdiff` along with `with=FALSE`.

```
DT[, setdiff(names(DT), cols.to.del), with=FALSE]
```

Comment: The third version is definitely my favorite. Thanks!

Comment: @paljenczy note that the third version doesn't remove the columns from `DT`; rather the output of that command is a _new_ `data.table` which you must _assign_ (by copying) to `DT`, which is likely inefficient.

Comment: @MichaelChirico noted, thanks!